# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime (valid UTC format)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize an XML object with the following node:

```
<startTime>2012-03-19T11:31:03.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2012-03-19T11:31:03.000Z</endTime>
```

Those are the properties on the class which I use to deserialize the XML into:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date", ElementName = "startTime")]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date", ElementName = "endTime")]
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Finally, this is the code I use to deserialize the XML:

```
Stream resultStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
return serializer.Deserialize(resultStream) as T;
```

However, the code will throw an Exception, telling me that the string was not recognized as a valid DateTime object - with a base exception saying that the XML file has errors at (1,1926) which points directly to the two timestamps.

All I can seem to find regarding this error message is caused by incorrect usage of formats (i.e. wrong special characters used in the date string). However, in my case, the format seems to comply 100% with the MSDN description.

Can anybody help me to point out the mistake?

Comment: You seem to be saying `DataType="date"` that you're expecting *only* a date - and yet you're supplying a date *and* a time. What happens if `DataType="dateTime"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `"dateTime"` `DataType` in your attributes - (watch the case: starting with a small `d`):

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "dateTime", ElementName = "startTime")]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "dateTime", ElementName = "endTime")]
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to Deserialize a `DateTime` using the `Time` format which can't work. But you don't get an error message at compilation because the `DataType` is a string.

You should try:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "dateTime", ElementName = "startTime")]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "dateTime", ElementName = "endTime")]
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```